# md5 exclude php

Tags: php, md5

This php I wrote has a syntax error on line 9 as reported by dreamweaver, but i cannot figure it out. can someone help me please? The intent of the script is to take an md5 file containing email addresses to compare against our data and exclude those lines from the output file.

```
<?php
$suppressions = file_get_contents("suppressions.txt");
$emails = file_get_contents("emails.txt");
$email_check = explode($emails,"\r\n");
$suppression_check = explode($suppressions,"\r\n");
foreach($email_check as $email)
{
$email_md5 = md5($email)
foreach($suppression_check as $suppression)
{
if($email_md5 == $suppression)
{
file_put_contents("emails_suppressed.txt",$email);
}
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Try adding a semicolon at the end of `md5($email)`

Comment: You missed a semicolon at line 8.

Comment: It often starts with proper indenting. But that is just a hint, there is nobody forcing you to do that :)

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon:

```
Line 8: $email_md5 = md5($email);
```

Answer (score 1):

the error would have been Unexpected foreach on Line 9, you need to end line 8 first with a semi-colon ";"

```
Line 8: $email_md5 = md5($email);
```